# Left join with result of COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, coalesce

```
    SELECT  *
      FROM  TBDA temp
 LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
            (
              COALESCE (
                 (
                    SELECT sum_payment
                      FROM TBDA_REPAYMENT 
                     WHERE isdn = temp.isdn
                       AND tr_month = temp.tr_month
                       AND tr_year = temp.tr_year 
                ),
                 (
                    SELECT sum_payment
                      FROM TBDA_PAYNEW 
                     WHERE isdn = temp.isdn
                       AND tr_month = temp.tr_month
                       AND tr_year = temp.tr_year 
                )
              )
            )
          )
```

> - TBDA table has isdn,tr_month,tr_year
> - TBDA_REPAYMENT table has isdn,tr_month,tr_year,sum_payment
> - TBDA_PAYNEW table has isdn,tr_month,tr_year,sum_payment

Expected result :

A table off all fields of TBDA  with sum_payment, look for sum_payment from two tables (TBDA_REPAYMENT & TBDA_PAYNEW) by ISDN (TBDA table) by comparing isdn,tr_month,tr_year, if sum_payment exists in one of two tables (TBDA_REPAYMENT & TBDA_PAYNEW) then add it to the results, otherwise it's null.

I get the error :

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Try running sub queries separately, and you'll find the problem.

Comment: `SELECT
 COALESCE (
  (
   SELECT
    sum_payment
   FROM
    TBDA_REPAYMENT
   WHERE
    isdn='abc' and tr_month='01' and tr_year='2018'
  ),
  (
   SELECT
    sum_payment
   FROM
    TBDA_PAYNEW
   WHERE
    isdn='abc' and tr_month='01' and tr_year='2018'
  )
 )` This does not give any error.

Comment: Now set an alias for selected column to this query. Like `select coalesce('a', 'b') as somealias`.

Comment: `SELECT COALESCE ( ( SELECT sum_payment FROM TBDA_REPAYMENT as a WHERE isdn = 'abc' AND tr_month = '01' AND tr_year = '2018' ), ( SELECT sum_payment FROM TBDA_PAYNEW as b WHERE isdn = 'abc' AND tr_month = '01' AND tr_year = '2018' ) ) as something ` it works here, but not for the whole statement I posted in the question.

Comment: Have you checked the answer below.. ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TBDA temp
Cross Apply (   SELECT  COALESCE (
                        (
                            SELECT
                                sum_payment
                            FROM
                                TBDA_REPAYMENT 
                            WHERE
                                isdn = temp.isdn
                            AND tr_month = temp.tr_month
                            AND tr_year = temp.tr_year 
                        ),
                        (
                            SELECT
                                sum_payment
                            FROM
                                TBDA_PAYNEW 
                            WHERE
                                isdn = temp.isdn
                            AND tr_month = temp.tr_month
                            AND tr_year = temp.tr_year 
                        )   
                    ) as First_Null_Value

            ) as value_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless a CROSS JOIN, CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY is used, the ON clause is required.
Hence the error.
Although you could still do something like `... LEFT JOIN othertable ON (1=1)`.

But you could re-write this query using 2 left joins.

```
select 
 temp.*,
 coalesce(repay.sum_payment, paynew.sum_payment) as value_table
from TBDA temp
left join TBDA_REPAYMENT repay on (repay.isdn = temp.isdn and repay.tr_month = temp.tr_month and repay.tr_year = temp.tr_year)
left join TBDA_PAYNEW paynew on (paynew.isdn = temp.isdn and paynew.tr_month = temp.tr_month and paynew.tr_year = temp.tr_year);
```

Note that there's an assumption that the tables TBDA_REPAYMENT & TBDA_PAYNEW have a uniqueness on the 3 fields used in the join (isdn, tr_month, tr_year).

Or the OUTER APPLY syntax could be used.
And if there's no uniqueness on (isdn, tr_month, tr_year) then you can use that to SUM the total at the same time.

```
select 
 temp.*, repay.sum_payment as repay_sum_payment, paynew.sum_payment as  paynew_sum_payment,
 coalesce(repay.sum_payment, paynew.sum_payment) as value_table
from TBDA temp
outer apply
(
  select nullif(sum(rp.sum_payment),0) as sum_payment
  from TBDA_REPAYMENT rp 
  where rp.isdn = temp.isdn 
    and rp.tr_month = temp.tr_month 
    and rp.tr_year = temp.tr_year
) as repay
outer apply 
(
  select nullif(sum(pn.sum_payment),0) as sum_payment
  from TBDA_PAYNEW pn 
  where pn.isdn = temp.isdn 
    and pn.tr_month = temp.tr_month 
    and pn.tr_year = temp.tr_year
) as paynew;
```

**Example Snippet:**

```
declare @TBDA table (isdn int, tr_month int, tr_year int);
declare @TBDA_REPAYMENT table (isdn int, tr_month int, tr_year int, sum_payment int);
declare @TBDA_PAYNEW  table (isdn int, tr_month int, tr_year int, sum_payment int);

insert into @TBDA (isdn, tr_month, tr_year) values (1,6,2018),(2,6,2018);
insert into @TBDA_REPAYMENT (isdn, tr_month, tr_year, sum_payment) values (1,6,2018, 100);
insert into @TBDA_PAYNEW (isdn, tr_month, tr_year, sum_payment) values (1,6,2018, 200),(2,6,2018,100),(2,6,2018,200);

--
-- Using left join
--
select 
 temp.*, repay.sum_payment, paynew.sum_payment,
 coalesce(repay.sum_payment, paynew.sum_payment) as value_table
from @TBDA temp
left join @TBDA_REPAYMENT repay on (repay.isdn = temp.isdn and repay.tr_month = temp.tr_month and repay.tr_year = temp.tr_year)
left join @TBDA_PAYNEW paynew on (paynew.isdn = temp.isdn and paynew.tr_month = temp.tr_month and paynew.tr_year = temp.tr_year);

--
-- Using outer apply
--
select 
 temp.*, repay.sum_payment as repay_sum_payment, paynew.sum_payment as  paynew_sum_payment,
 coalesce(repay.sum_payment, paynew.sum_payment) as value_table
from @TBDA temp
outer apply
(
  select nullif(sum(rp.sum_payment),0) as sum_payment
  from @TBDA_REPAYMENT rp 
  where rp.isdn = temp.isdn 
    and rp.tr_month = temp.tr_month 
    and rp.tr_year = temp.tr_year
) as repay
outer apply 
(
  select nullif(sum(pn.sum_payment),0) as sum_payment
  from @TBDA_PAYNEW pn 
  where pn.isdn = temp.isdn 
    and pn.tr_month = temp.tr_month 
    and pn.tr_year = temp.tr_year
) as paynew;
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to not specifying `ON` condition on `LEFT JOIN`.

`LEFT JOIN` without `ON` will throw an error.

If you don't want to specify any condition, try `CROSS JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Just use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT t.*,
       IFNULL (  (SELECT r.sum_payment
                   FROM TBDA_REPAYMENT r
                   WHERE r.isdn = t.isdn AND
                         r.tr_month = t.tr_month AND
                         r.tr_year = t.tr_year 
                  ),
                  (SELECT p.sum_payment
                   FROM TBDA_PAYNEW p
                   WHERE p.isdn = t.isdn AND
                         p.tr_month = t.tr_month AND
                         p.tr_year = t.tr_year 
                  )
               )
        )
FROM TBDA t;
```

Although you can use `APPLY`, the use of `SELECT` is already insisting that at most one row be returned from the subqueries.

Also note a couple of things.  First, I replaced `COALESCE()` with `IFNULL()`.  Although I much prefer `COALESCE()` (because it is the standard and more flexible), the code is more efficient with `IFNULL()`.  `COALESCE()` causes SQL Server to evaluate the first argument twice when it is not `NULL`.

Second, table aliases and qualified column names should be used everywhere in the query.